# How to transform list to other format in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I get data in this format..

```
ListA =
[
    [('test1', 'aaa', 'A'),('test2', 'bbb', 'B'),('test3', 'ccc', 'C')],
    [('test4', 'ddd', 'D'),('test5', 'eee', 'E'),('test6', 'fff', 'F')],
    [('test7', 'ggg', 'A'),('test8', 'hhh', 'B'),('test9', 'ppp', 'C')]
]
```

and I would like to transform to this format

```
ID, ColA, ColB, ColC,
1, 'test1', 'aaa', 'A'
1, 'test2', 'bbb', 'B'
1, 'test3', 'ccc', 'C'
2, 'test4', 'ddd', 'D'
2, 'test5', 'eee', 'E'
2, 'test6', 'fff', 'F'
3, 'test7', 'ggg', 'A'
3, 'test8', 'hhh', 'B'
3, 'test9', 'ppp', 'C'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
df = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(ListA),
                  columns=['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'])
```

output:

```
    ColA ColB ColC
0  test1  aaa    A
1  test2  bbb    B
2  test3  ccc    C
3  test4  ddd    D
4  test5  eee    E
5  test6  fff    F
6  test7  ggg    A
7  test8  hhh    B
8  test9  ppp    C
```

with the index (can handle uneven list lengths):

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

idx = np.repeat(np.arange(len(ListA))+1, list(map(len, ListA)))

df = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(ListA),
                  columns=['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'],
                  index=idx).rename_axis('ID')
```

output:

```
     ColA ColB ColC
ID                 
1   test1  aaa    A
1   test2  bbb    B
1   test3  ccc    C
2   test4  ddd    D
2   test5  eee    E
2   test6  fff    F
3   test7  ggg    A
3   test8  hhh    B
3   test9  ppp    C
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested list-comprehension to the rescue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[tup for sublist in ListA for tup in sublist],
    columns=['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'])
```

Output:

```
    ColA ColB ColC
1  test1  aaa    A
1  test2  bbb    B
1  test3  ccc    C
2  test4  ddd    D
2  test5  eee    E
2  test6  fff    F
3  test7  ggg    A
3  test8  hhh    B
3  test9  ppp    C
```

If you want the index preserved as in your expected output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=[tup for sublist in ListA for tup in sublist],
        columns=['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'],
        index=np.arange(len(ListA)).repeat([len(sublist) for sublist in ListA])+1)
```

Comment: I actually had an issue with the second one (tried on 2x the provided input (`ListA = ListA*2`) and it fails)

Comment: @mozway Indeed; it only worked because the number of items in each tuple was the same as the number of tuples in the list :) fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `explode` to preserve the index:

```
df = pd.Series(ListA).explode().pipe(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(), index=x.index + 1, columns=['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC']))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    ColA ColB ColC
1  test1  aaa    A
1  test2  bbb    B
1  test3  ccc    C
2  test4  ddd    D
2  test5  eee    E
2  test6  fff    F
3  test7  ggg    A
3  test8  hhh    B
3  test9  ppp    C
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, another solution using `pandas.concat`:

```
df = (pd
 .concat(dict(enumerate(map(pd.DataFrame, ListA), start=1)))
 .droplevel(1)
 .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'])))
)
```

or:

```
from itertools import count
c = count(1)
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, index=[next(c)]*len(x),
                             columns=['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'])
                for x in ListA])
```

output:

```
    ColA ColB ColC
1  test1  aaa    A
1  test2  bbb    B
1  test3  ccc    C
2  test4  ddd    D
2  test5  eee    E
2  test6  fff    F
3  test7  ggg    A
3  test8  hhh    B
3  test9  ppp    C
```